# Dataframe Timestamp Filter for new/repeating value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have data which ahs been converted into a two column dataframe. There is a `Local Date_Local Time` column, and a `Close` column. The data is stock/index data.

The timestamps in are by the minute. Example

*sample from my df*

```
index   Local Date_Local Time   Close
0       2019-07-31 23:10:00     2980.38
1       2019-07-31 22:21:00     2980.38
```

Not every minute of every day is in the index. Since this is trading data, then some hours during the night or morning are included, but it doesn't have 0:00-23:59 for each day. There are two things I need to do, but this question is about the first one.

Trading doesn't start or stop at the exact same minute everyday. This data also cover several months meaning timezone/clock change could have change the relative hour that trading starts.

However, when trading stops `Close` will begin to repeat, and when it starts `Close` will stop repeating.

*sample from the raw data (in df, it will look as above)*

```
30-Jul-2019,15:32,"3,003.01"
30-Jul-2019,15:31,"3,004.43" <--- this is where trading began
29-Jul-2019,23:14,"3,020.97" <-- repeating price while market was closed
29-Jul-2019,22:21,"3,020.97"
29-Jul-2019,22:20,"3,020.97"
```

If I assume something like **"Close price will never bee the same down to the last two decimals for more than 4 minutes"**, how can I filter this dataframe to include each trading day

- from the first new price (e.g. @ 15:31 above)
- to the last change in price aka first instance of a price that will repeat more than 4 times

*(example from raw data)*

```
29-Jul-2019,22:09,"3,020.97"  
29-Jul-2019,22:08,"3,020.97"  
29-Jul-2019,22:07,"3,020.97"  
29-Jul-2019,22:06,"3,020.97"  
29-Jul-2019,22:05,"3,020.97" <-- we want this, first repeating one  
29-Jul-2019,22:04,"3,020.98" <-- below this, things still change
29-Jul-2019,22:03,"3,020.97"  
29-Jul-2019,22:02,"3,020.94"  
29-Jul-2019,22:01,"3,020.89"
```

The jump between timestamps might help, but I can't manipulate dataframes well.

Again data will be as in the df above and sample below. Raw data was to show how things change. `Local Date_Local Time` is already `datetime64[ns] and`Close`is already`float64`

```
    Local Date_Local Time   Close
90  2019-07-31 20:52:00     2971.61
91  2019-07-31 20:51:00     2975.38
92  2019-07-31 20:50:00     2981.48
93  2019-07-31 20:49:00     2985.19
```

In the end result, for example `2019-07-29 22:05` would be right below `2019-07-30 15:31`, since everything between repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works for you

```
df['diff']=df.groupby('Day')['Value'].diff().ne(0)
a=((df.reset_index().groupby('diff')['index'].apply(np.array))[0])[:4]
df.drop(a,inplace=True)
df.drop('diff',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

the `[:4]` is based on the table where the time is in descending order. if the time is in descending order, you will have to change this to `[-3:]`.
With the above code, I stared with

```
Day     Time    Value
0   29-Jul-19   22:09   3,020.97
1   29-Jul-19   22:08   3,020.97
2   29-Jul-19   22:07   3,020.97
3   29-Jul-19   22:06   3,020.97
4   29-Jul-19   22:05   3,020.97
5   29-Jul-19   22:04   3,020.98
6   29-Jul-19   22:03   3,020.97
7   29-Jul-19   22:02   3,020.94
8   29-Jul-19   22:01   3,020.89
9   29-Jul-19   22:01   3,020.91
10  29-Jul-19   22:01   3,020.98
11  29-Jul-19   22:01   3,020.98
12  29-Jul-19   22:01   3,020.92
```

and ended up with this

```
Day     Time    Value
0   29-Jul-19   22:09   3020.97
5   29-Jul-19   22:04   3020.98
6   29-Jul-19   22:03   3020.97
7   29-Jul-19   22:02   3020.94
8   29-Jul-19   22:01   3020.89
9   29-Jul-19   22:01   3020.91
10  29-Jul-19   22:01   3020.98
11  29-Jul-19   22:01   3020.98
12  29-Jul-19   22:01   3020.92
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to split out the time? In my df the datetime is one column `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:00`. Second column is the close price. I will try to modify this a bit.

Comment: in that case, use `df['diff']=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D'))['Value'].diff().ne(0)` instead of `df['diff']=df.groupby('Day')['Value'].diff().ne(0)`. here `key` is the column name of the datetime object.

Comment: Hi @mohanys. this worked well. I changed to `.diff(2)` so that it compares with 2 minutes prior. I will have anther question or two about filtering the data now. Hope you can help. Thanks.