# Filter DataFrame on diff, where boolean repeats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

**Background**

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536141/dataframe-timestamp-filter-for-new-repeating-value), I wanted to detect when the value in a price column started repeating.
The reason for this, is to filter/drop rows from the dataframe where things begin to repeat.

*The data is a financial time-series and will be fed to an ANN. Repeated prices indicate closed markets - useless for trend prediction*

The solution used was

`df2['diff'] = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Local Date_Local Time', freq='H'))['Close'].diff(2).ne(0)`

- Groups by `Local Date_Local Time`, and looks at the `Close` value
- If the current Close price is **not** different from the `Close` 2 minutes ago, return `False`

This works okay, but there are times when the price will return to what it was two minutes ago. However, I will assume (and check later in the filtered data) that this won't happen for two consecutive minutes (i.e. price at 0 = price at 2, and price at 1 = price at 3).

Data: three columns "Local Date_Local Time", "Close", "diff"
Total Rows: 67K

```
        Local Date_Local Time   Close       diff
201     2019-07-31 19:01:00     3014.74     True
202     2019-07-31 19:00:00     3014.98     True
203     2019-07-31 18:59:00     3014.92     True
204     2019-07-31 18:58:00     3014.68     False <-- *
205     2019-07-31 18:57:00     3014.51     True
206     2019-07-31 18:56:00     3014.68     True  <-- because of this
207     2019-07-31 18:55:00     3014.62     True
208     2019-07-31 18:54:00     3014.53     True
209     2019-07-31 18:53:00     3014.22     True
210     2019-07-31 18:52:00     3014.43     True
211     2019-07-31 18:51:00     3014.09     True
212     2019-07-31 18:50:00     3014.11     True
213     2019-07-31 18:49:00     3014.37     True
214     2019-07-31 18:48:00     3014.19     True
215     2019-07-31 18:47:00     3014.80     True
216     2019-07-31 18:46:00     3014.77     True
217     2019-07-31 18:45:00     3014.28     True <-- *
218     2019-07-31 18:44:00     3014.28     True
219     2019-07-31 18:43:00     3014.01     True <-- because of this
220     2019-07-31 18:42:00     3014.07     True
221     2019-07-31 18:41:00     3013.90     True
222     2019-07-31 18:40:00     3014.02     True
```

* If I had used `.diff(1)` then row 217 would show False, and row 204 would be True. Unfortunately, it compares a specific prior minute, not "that last x minutes".

While line 204 says false, it should remain and not be removed, as there is still activity going on, versus the price going stale when trading stops.

**Question**

How can I drop rows from this dataframe (or a copy), so that for places where `diff` column shows `False` 2 or more times, until that stops?

Turn this

```
10      2019-07-31 22:12:00     2980.38     False
11      2019-07-31 22:11:00     2980.38     False
12      2019-07-31 22:10:00     2980.38     False
13      2019-07-31 22:09:00     2980.38     False
14      2019-07-31 22:08:00     2980.38     False
15      2019-07-31 22:07:00     2980.38     True
16      2019-07-31 22:06:00     2980.38     True
17      2019-07-31 22:05:00     2980.37     True
18      2019-07-31 22:04:00     2980.36     True
19      2019-07-31 22:03:00     2980.32     True
```

Into this (or even remove row 13 as well)

```
13      2019-07-31 22:09:00     2980.38     False
14      2019-07-31 22:08:00     2980.38     False
15      2019-07-31 22:07:00     2980.38     True
16      2019-07-31 22:06:00     2980.38     True
17      2019-07-31 22:05:00     2980.37     True
18      2019-07-31 22:04:00     2980.36     True
19      2019-07-31 22:03:00     2980.32     True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works for you

```
a=((df.reset_index().groupby('diff')['index'].apply(np.array))[0])[:3]
df.drop(a,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going a different direction with this. The help from your initial solution got me from 64K, to 16K rows. I did some manual checking, and noticed enough patterns to create some new filters I could use with `.loc` method. It ended up being quite hard-coded but I can move to the next step now.